# Jquery Add function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some code that creates a div inside my jQuery plugin but the add function doesnt work, it adds the css to all elements on the page.

I want to create a `<div>` inside the element I am calling my plugin upon using `$('element').initResource({});`. How do I do that?

```
(function ( $ )
{
    var initResource = function (options, element)
    {
        this.test();

        this.options = $.extend(this.defaults, options);
        this.el = element;

        this.renderFilters();
    };

    initResource.prototype =
    {
        constructor: initResource,

        options: {},
        defaults:
        {
            base_url: '',
            intended_action: 'link',
            group_div: '',
            used_filters: [],
            data_type: 'student'
        },

        el: null,

        addPanel: function ()
        {
            var panel = this.el.add("p"); // doesnt work
            panel.css({
                "border": "1px solid cornflowerblue",
                "border-radius": "4px",
                "margin-left": "5px",
                "margin-right": "5px",
                "margin-bottom": "15px",
                "padding-top": "5px"
            });

            return panel;
        },

        renderFilters: function ()
        {
            var filters = this.addPanel.add('div'); // doesnt work               
        },

    };

    $.fn.initResource = function(options)
    {
        var iR = new initResource(options, this);
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: How **exactly** are you using this method? Your `el` property looks like it's an arbitrary jQuery object, and like most jQuery methods `.add()` operates on all elements involved.

Comment: `this.el` works, it refers to the jQuery object, lets say if I call the plugin using `$('element').initResource()`, it will refer to the `$('element')` object

Comment: well in reality i am calling it with $('.myClass')` , so it is a class only used once. it could be an id, but no difference.

Comment: I even explicitly changed it to `var panel = $('#myId').add('div')` and same thing happened. its exactly like on jquery's website

Comment: [Wait a sec - you know what `.add()` does, right?](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

Comment: Calling `$("#myId").add('div')` creates a jQuery object with just the "myId" element in it, and then adds to that jQuery object all the `<div>` elements on the page. Are you looking for `.append()`?